# String to number. Same delimiter for variables and decimals. Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, textscan

I have a string with six values:

```
datastring = A, 12229, 1480413555450, 139,1473389, 012,3362331, -001,7571955
```

where the first one is a letter and the rest are float number, I would like to get the numeric values using:

```
data=textscan(datastring,'%s %f %f %f %f %f','Delimiter',',');
```

The problem is, as you see, that both the decimals, and the different values, are separate by `,`, so do you have any idea how I could do that?

PS: I also tried with delimiter being `', '`, that is with an space, but isnt working neither.

Comment: What a terrible format. Cant you make sure that is not used? having the same  character to separate values and decimals screams "failure"

Comment: I know the format is terrible, but I cant do anything with it. Im just exporting the data from an app in Android to Matlab

Comment: I'd replace every `, ` with something else before `textscan`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the ", " to something else that wont be in the string, then convert the remaining "," to a "." and then use your original code but change the delimiter to "something else", e.g.

```
tempStr = regexprep ( regexprep ( datastring, ', ', '# ' ), ',', '.' );
data=textscan(tempStr,'%s %f %f %f %f %f','Delimiter','#')
```

Comment: Thanks! It wasnt so difficult actually, but I havent thought in this solution